# U-Joints for a Pickup

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, u-joint

I am in need of U-Joints for my 06 Chevy Silverado 1500 Ext Cab Short Bed Z71 LT3 L33 4L60e pickup truck. The issue I'm having is, when I looked it up on RockAuto.com (my go to site), I found there are about 80-90 different U-Joints they have listed. There is a huge overlap of what *might* be right and I don't have clue.

- Does anyone have a good reference or a good way to tell how to which U-Joint is needed for any given application?
- Is there a specific way to measure them which allows a person to find them easily or to match them to what is needed?
- Do auto makers tend to stay with one size across their product lines?
- Any other pertinent information you might have?

Comment: Which engine? 1500/2500/HD? Which transmission?

Comment: @Ben - Updated. Please remember, though, while I'm looking for which exact ones I need, but also, how does one *easily differentiate* for their own trucks. Trying to make this more of a generic question than specific to GM trucks or something.

Comment: easy differentiation may be hard, u joints are a PITA even on common trucks like c/k vin chevys.

Comment: @Ben - Okay, now I don't feel so bad about not knowing, lol. Give me what you got!

Comment: and more questions 4wd? bed size? standard? long?

Comment: @Ben - You just gotta know, don't cha! Added to body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so this is pretty specific and I had to look through 4 pages of u-joints after narrowing down by engine/transmission and body style. Yet there were even more options.

I'm making assumptions at this point, as quadrasteer isn't that common and since you said you have a short bed, you should have a 1 piece aluminum drive shaft. This would probably be easier by VIN but...

Try this it's a NAPA part number, SKF brand. Should be easy to do an interchange on the number.

UJS UJ534G This looks like it's used for the front and rear my vision got blurry around page 3 so you're probably going to have to measure the outer diameter of the bearing cap on the u-joint.

> w/ Extended Cab;w/ Automatic Transmission;w/ Regular Cab;w/ Standard
>   Bed
>
> Bearing Cap O.D. 1 : 1.125"
>   Construction : ISR (Inside Retained)
>   Inside Lock Up 1 : 2.557"
>   Lube Fitting Location : In Cross
>   Series : Mechanics 3
>   Style : 4 Grooved Round Bearings

Here's one from a different manufacturer with a nifty measuring diagram

[image]

TWD 5795X

> Body Styles : Pickup (Ext'd Cab 4 Dr.) Comments: Front Shaft Front And
>   Rear Joint;w/ Standard Bed;Non-Greasable Per Car Qty: 2
>
> Bearing Cap Diameter : 1.125"
>   Bearing Plate Diameter : N/A
>   Bolt Hole Circle Diameter : N/A
>   Cross Dimensions : N/A
>   Fits Driveline Series : SPL25 / S44
>   Greasable : No
>   Outside Snap Ring U-Joint Cross Trunnion Diameter : N/A
>   Outside Snap Ring U-Joint Overall Cross Length : N/A
>   Snap Ring Dimension : 2.556"
>   Snap Ring Inside
>   U-Joint Cross Trunnion Diameter : N/A
>   U-Joint Bearing Type : Inside Snap Ring
>   U-Joint End Yoke Dimensions : N/A
>   Contents : U-Joint, Caps & Snap Rings
>   UNSPSC : 25173810

---

As to the other questions

> Does anyone have a good reference or a good way to tell how to which
>   U-Joint is needed for any given application?

Maybe something exists to make this easier but I'm still stuck in the past when it comes to looking up parts. Most trucks have far too many options for this to ever be easy.

For example on this truck you need to know

- The size of the bed standard/long
- The size of the cab
- standard/crew/extended
- Which transmission style automatic/manual?
- Which Transmission 4l60e/5lm60?
- 4WD or 2WD?
- 1500/2500/3500/HD/etc...
- Does the truck have Quadrasteer?
- Is the driveshaft aluminum or steel?
- How many sections on the driveshaft?
- Depending on previous configurations which u-joint front, rear or
  possibly center?

I'm sure I missed an option or two here...

> Is there a specific way to measure them which allows a person to find
>   them easily or to match them to what is needed?

See attached diagram.

> Do auto makers tend to stay with one size across their product lines?

In my experience... No.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I think I knew most all of this, but your answer is awesome. I'll cross ref as you suggested. I applaud you as my eyes went blurry around the first page. You're assumptions were correct. No Quadrasteer. I'm pretty sure it's a one piece aluminum, but I haven't been under there to look at it recently.

Comment: I just went out and measured the best I could with an inside slide micrometer. I can confirm it is a one piece aluminum DS. The best measurement I could come up with on the DS loop was 1.1875"-ish or 30.17mm. This seems a little bit larger than the 1.125" on the one given. Could just be the difference to allow the cap to insert into the DS loop, but who knows. Problem I have is I need to order them before I can take the old ones out.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 OK so I noticed when I was looking through the u joints that the w/ quadrasteer w/ crewcab u joints measure the outer diameter of the bearing cap at 1.188" the inside lockup is 3.622". I think you should be able to unbolt the straps at the rear u joint to measure unless it's one of those plate deals. Probably a good idea to make sure that both caps are the same size I know they do that sometimes too... front UJS UJ231 rear UJS UJ331 for reference.